# Convert CGPathRef to CGMutablePathRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

How can i convert `CGPathRef` to `CGMutablePathRef`.

I think this are Structure not class so no API available to convert.

**code:-**

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0);
CGPathRef intermediatePath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(pt.custompath, &transform);
```

How to save intermediatePath variable to `CGMutablePathRef`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CGPathCreateMutableCopy().

```
CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(intermediatePath);
```